# How to change the caret color in JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2

We want to migrate a project from Swing to JavaFX as the new UI technology. As a part of our corporate design, we were changing the caret color in Swing to a light green.

How can we alter the color(or maybe also other things about the appearance) of carets in JavaFX 2.0? I couldn't find any useful information about it. I saw that it was possible in earlier versions of JavaFX, so i guess there's a way in 2.0 too.

Kind regards,

David

Comment: Related question: [Hide input caret of TextField in JavaFX8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315861/hide-input-caret-of-textfield-in-javafx8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the TextField caret has the same color as text. You can change them by:

```
    TextField tf = new TextField("Text");
    tf.setStyle("  -fx-text-fill: green");
```

or globally in css file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In our case, text color and caret color should be different. This results in a very nice-looking effect and that's our goal. Well, even if it's not possible for now, i hope they'll add this feature to one of the next releases.

Comment: I've filed feature request for that: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-20891

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey's answer should work fine.. However it does not work with texarea since it is a bug..U can download java fx 2.1 developer preview to make it work with textarea