# Hide input caret of TextField in JavaFX8

Tags: javafx, focus, textfield, javafx-8, caret

I would like to hide the input caret of a TextField in JavaFX8. I already tried to set the text fill to white (my TextField has a white background), but then my user input also disappears.

The problem is that the textfield still needs focus, so I also thought of some EventHandler which listens to user input, and focusses on the textfield when a key is pressed, but then I would miss the first key typed.

Anyone that knows how to do this? Or is it not possible in JavaFX8?

Comment: Related question: [How to change the caret color in JavaFX 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057989/how-to-change-the-caret-color-in-javafx-2-0).

Comment: Related question: [How can I turn off the blinking cursor in a TextArea in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597180/how-can-i-turn-off-the-blinking-cursor-in-a-textarea-in-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update for Java 8u40*

A CSS style class was added to JavaFX to switch on and off the text field caret which is (in most cases) a better solution than the custom skin approach in this answer.

This property can be applied in CSS to any text area or text field:

```
-fx-display-caret: false;
```

For more details, see the related question:

- [How can I turn off the blinking cursor in a TextArea in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597180/how-can-i-turn-off-the-blinking-cursor-in-a-textarea-in-java)

---

You could use a [custom skin](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Controls) to control the text field caret.

[image: sample image]

*Sample Skin*

Allows you to specify the caret color in the constructor.

CAUTION: this solution extends from a com.sun class so it is not guaranteed to continue working in future JavaFX versions.  (This solution was tested against Java8u25 and worked for that version).

I suggest that you [create a feature request in the JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) requesting more control over the caret using publicly supported methods (e.g. the addition of new css properties to control the caret appearance).

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TextFieldSkin;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class TextFieldCaretControlSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
    public TextFieldCaretControlSkin(TextField textField, Color caretColor) {
        super(textField);

        setCaretColor(caretColor);
    }

    private void setCaretColor(Color color) {
        caretPath.strokeProperty().unbind();
        caretPath.fillProperty().unbind();

        caretPath.setStroke(color);
        caretPath.setFill(color);
    }
}
```

*Sample Application*

Demonstrates the use of the custom TextFieldCaretControlSkin.

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CaretColorizer extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField redCaretTextField = new TextField("Red Caret");
        redCaretTextField.setSkin(
                new TextFieldCaretControlSkin(
                        redCaretTextField,
                        Color.RED
                )
        );

        TextField noCaretTextField = new TextField("No Caret");
        noCaretTextField.setSkin(
                new TextFieldCaretControlSkin(
                        noCaretTextField,
                        Color.TRANSPARENT
                )
        );

        TextField normalTextField = new TextField("Standard Caret");

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                10,
                redCaretTextField,
                noCaretTextField,
                normalTextField
        );

        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Really great approach for this problem, and I prefer this solution. May it ever stop working, other people can always use my hacky solution. I will also request this feature, also thanks for mentioning that!

Answer (score 6):

I already found a workaround for this, and I want to share this with you of course. If anyone else wants to hide the caret until user input, you can use this:

I have created a change listener, which changes the text color on user input.

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
                String oldValue, String newValue) {

            if (!textfield.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                textfield.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black");
            } else {
                textfield.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white");
            }

        }

});
```

Make sure the text fill is white on startup, I did this in the css file of my FXML:

```
#textfield {
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

Sorry for bothering you all with this question. However, this subject is not greatly discussed online, so I hope it could be useful for some of you.