# How can I turn off the blinking cursor in a TextArea in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, textarea

In Perl Tk the trick is that you can set the 'insert on time' of a text widget to 0, which has the effect of turning off the blinking cursor:

```
$self->{status_line}=$self->{status_frame}->Text(
-width=>80,-font=>[-size=>10],-height=>1,
-insertontime=>0)->pack(-side=>'left');
```

Is there an equivalent of this in Java to turn off the blinking cursor?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [Hide input caret of TextField in JavaFX8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315861/hide-input-caret-of-textfield-in-javafx8), but I won't make it as a duplicate as James' answer is  better than any current answers in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in CSS with

```
-fx-display-caret: false ;
```

either inline:

```
textArea.setStyle("-fx-display-caret: false;");
```

or in an external CSS file:

```
.text-area {
    -fx-display-caret: false ;
}
```

Comment: Not really: I just read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textinputcontrol) ;) Mark the answer as correct, though, if it does what you need. That way it will be easier for other users to find it.