# There is a way to change text Selection Handle cursor style on javafx mobile?

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm not sure this css problem or something else. Javafx doesn't have css styling for text selection cursor because maybe javafx not designed to be a mobile application. When I'm searching about it. I found css styling for input caret. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315861/hide-input-caret-of-textfield-in-javafx8) but that's not the case for the problem i have. Any help would be appreciated.

**Here there sample what i want**.
[image]

**Here is my javafx project after porting into android**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.

JavaFX's built in controls `TextField` and `TextArea` define the caret node, using `caretHandle, selectionHandle1, selectionHandle2` stackpanes with CSS style classes `caret-handle` and `selection-handle`.

This is still valid in the latest [JavaFX version](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin/TextInputControlSkin.java#L257):

```
caretHandle.getStyleClass().setAll("caret-handle");
selectionHandle1.getStyleClass().setAll("selection-handle");
selectionHandle2.getStyleClass().setAll("selection-handle");
```

On a regular desktop platform, you would use `modena.css`, where the `caret-handle`, `selection-handle` style classes are not used.

However in other platforms like Android, where `embedded.css` or `touch.css` are [used](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/db7b26f96b8b9f29656bfbef1732b7f2570eccf1/modules/javafx.graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/application/PlatformImpl.java#L809), these do use the [style classes](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/4f0addff16de7182752bc60541f44baeb0e99d2a/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/touch.css#L141):

```
.caret-handle {
    -fx-background-color: transparent,
                          black /*#ACACAC*/,
                          linear-gradient(to bottom, #AFAFAF 0%, #DFDFDF 100%);
    -fx-shape: "M11.974,2.579L20,12.358V20H4V12.356L11.974,2.579z";
...
```

The path in `-fx-shape` sets the shape you have posted in your picture:

[image]

Being set by CSS, you can always override the shape with your own.

You just need to add it to your CSS file, like:

```
.caret-handle {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-shape: "M 100,100 m -75,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0z";
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.5em;
}
```

that will give you:

[image]