# How to change mouse cursor when I hover over javafx TextArea?

Tags: java, javafx, mouse-cursor

I want to change the TextArea cursor, but nothing happens when I use this:

```
numTextArea.setCursor(Cursor.DISAPPEAR);
```

Comment: This question is about the mouse cursor for the text area.  Just to avoid confusion for future readers that happen upon this question, there is a separate concept called a caret.  If, unlike this question, you really wanted to change the caret rather than the cursor, then see the answer to [Hide input caret of TextField in JavaFX8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27315861/hide-input-caret-of-textfield-in-javafx8)

Comment: Just to manage expectations about the caret mentioned by @jewelsea : JavaFX provides very little built-in customization for carets. You cannot control the caret animation with the _default_ skins of the text input controls. You also can't control the caret shape; at the lowest level, carets are "created" via `Text` or `TextFlow` (the former has a `caretShape` property, both have a `caretShape(int,boolean)` method), but that will always give you a thin vertical bar. Maybe one day they'll implement https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8256179.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default skin of `TextArea` includes a "content area", which [is documented](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area) as a `Region`. It's this content area that has its cursor set to `Cursor.TEXT` (by the [default user agent stylesheet](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/25862787d2e1b6c4da17089a1d5695c4e4b9fd6e/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css#L1330)). And since the mouse is hovering over the content area, not the text area directly, you see the cursor of the content area instead of the text area.

The likely easiest way to change the cursor is to use CSS.

```css
.text-area .content {
    -fx-cursor: disappear;
}
```

Then add the stylesheet to the scene (or the text area, or an ancestor layout). For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final String CSS = """
            .text-area .content {
                -fx-cursor: hand;
            }
            """.stripIndent();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new TextArea(), 500, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("data:text/css," + CSS);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** The above adds the stylehseet to the scene via a [data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). This requires JavaFX 17+.</sup>

The example uses `Cursor.HAND` because `Cursor.DISAPPEAR` just gave me the default cursor on Windows 10 with Java/JavaFX 20.0.1. Not sure if that's a bug.

Note you can use `null` or `inherit` for `-fx-cursor` in the CSS, and then set the text area's cursor in code (like you're currently trying to do).