# javafx - easiest way of changing the caret color

Tags: css, javafx, skinning

I would like to set the caret color for **all** JavaFX text inputs (e.g. TextField, TextArea, the ones in ComboBox:editable, DatePicker, etc...)

I found this Stackoverflow answer: [How to change the caret color in JavaFX 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057989/how-to-change-the-caret-color-in-javafx-2-0)

... and an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/thejeed/javafx-caret-example).

The first one does change the text **and** the caret color which is not good. The second one extends the TextFieldSkin class, which is already better, but how can I use it in CSS?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

I found the following CSS style property for JavaFX controls: `-fx-skin`.

This would theoretically allow me to set a custom skin class (`-fx-skin: "package.MySkin";`), however, the skin class just isn't used!

The class looks like the following:

```
package gui;
…
public class MyTextFieldSkin extends TextFieldSkin
{
   public MyTextFieldSkin(TextField tf) {
      super(tf);
      System.out.println("MyTextFieldSkin constructor called!");
      ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Color> farbe = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(Color.green);
      caretPath.strokeProperty().bind(farbe);
      caretPath.setStrokeWidth(1.5);
   }
}
```

… and is set in CSS like that:

```
.text-field {
   -fx-skin: "gui.MyTextFieldSkin";
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I looked at the source code of [AquaFX](http://aquafx-project.com/downloads.html), and they are doing it the same way as me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of try & error, I solved the problem in the following way:

I gathered all `TextField`s and controls that have `TextField`s in them (like `ComboBox`, `DatePicker` and so on) inside a container recursively (in deference of `TitledPane`, `ScrollPane`, `SplitPane` and `TabPane`, because they don't publish their children in `getChildren()`, so one has to call the `getContent()` method of the individual classes and scan through it).

After I had all the `TextField` controls, I looped over them and changed their `Skin` with the following code:

```
public class MyTextFieldSkin extends TextFieldSkin {
   public MyTextFieldSkin(TextField tf)
   {
      super(tf);
      ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Color> color = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(Color.RED);
      caretPath.strokeProperty().bind(color);          
   }
}
```

Then I just had to call

```
textfield.setSkin(new MyTextFieldSkin(textfield));
```

and that was about it.

Cheers